# Highcharts JSON formatting - splitting up and preprocessing data for charts?

Tags: javascript, json, api, highcharts

I'm trying to get data from this JSON: https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=60&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG

into hightcharts.

I have this chart that is working properly, but I can't get proper formatting for JSON above: still learning javascript. And I like to learn on project, piece by piece, with some cause at least :)

Also, this timestamp is bugging me...

```
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-ohlcv.json&callback=?', function (data) {


var ohlc = [],
    volume = [],
    dataLength = data.length,

    groupingUnits = [[
        'week',                        
        [1]                             
    ], [
        'month',
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
    ]],

    i = 0;

for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
    ohlc.push([
        data[i][0], // the date
        data[i][1], // open
        data[i][2], // high
        data[i][3], // low
        data[i][4] // close
    ]);

    volume.push([
        data[i][0], // the date
        data[i][5] // the volume
    ]);
}


// create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'AAPL Historical'
    },

    yAxis: [{
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3
        },
        title: {
            text: 'OHLC'
        },
        height: '60%',
        lineWidth: 2,
        resize: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }, {
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Volume'
        },
        top: '65%',
        height: '35%',
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 2
    }],

    tooltip: {
        split: true
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'candlestick',
        name: 'AAPL',
        data: ohlc,
        dataGrouping: {
            units: groupingUnits
        }
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Volume',
        data: volume,
        yAxis: 1,
        dataGrouping: {
            units: groupingUnits
        }
    }]
});
});
```

Could someone help out? How to separate properly info from that JSON and format it so that highcharts can visualize it?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this **live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/8qk0mjzp/

`Data` property from object fetched via `getJSON()` contains the data to be plotted on the chart.

Every point has JSON format (not an array as in the code that you posted) so its properties need to be referred like this:

```
  for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
    ohlc.push([
      data[i].time * 1000, // the date
      data[i].open, // open
      data[i].high, // high
      data[i].low, // low
      data[i].close // close
    ]);

    volume.push([
      data[i].time * 1000, // the date
      data[i].volumefrom, // low
      data[i].volumeto // high
    ]);
  }
```

Comment: Fantastic, now I get it where it went wrong. Thank you very much for the effort and example!

Comment: Kamil, is there some way to contact you? I would want to ask for some modification for date filter, so that 1day, 1year etc and datepicker work. I would of course compensate you :) Please, I cannot find anyone to help me out with this.

I have example in Google charts, but can't apply it to hightcharts...

Comment: If you have any specific questions please ask them on stack overflow.

Comment: Ok, sorry, no problem. Im not managing to connect Zoom buttons(1m, 3, 6m, ytd...) with JSON. I have the JS logic to get api, but Im not managing to connect it to chart. This api has URL difference for 1h history, 1day history, 1 month and 1 year. So I presume the buttons should be correlated to url for the API. Here is the JS code: https://jsfiddle.net/9ao8qdj2/ - I would appreciate help very much. Thanks anyway!

Comment: By default **range selector** buttons are used for setting extremes. You can provide your own logic (e.g. fetching the data from some other API and updating the chart with it) and prevent the default action by using `rangeSelector.buttons.events.click` (https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.buttons.events.click).